# Black Screen in iOS 13 when change Storybord View Controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios13, xcode11, uiscenedelegate

In iOS 13 when i call to other StoryBoard, when charge the ViewController appear a black screen on my view.

I use this code for call a new StoryBoard:

```
UIStoryboard *homeSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:SBNameHome bundle:nil];
UIViewController *homeVC = [homeSB instantiateInitialViewController];
homeVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
homeVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:homeVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This project use multiple StoryBoards, and when i call a new StoryBoard fail. If i build a new ViewController with Xib, don't appear the black screen, but the project was built with multiple StoryBoard instead of Xib. 
I think that this is caused by the new SceneDelegate in iOS 13.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Is your homeVC is empty? I mean it might be possible that because of dark mode and empty view controller you are facing this issue

Comment: The application is fully developed and worked perfectly on iOS 12 and earlier, but with iOS 13 it has stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

@Antonio Ureba

Try the presentation style

```
UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen
```

Comment: The first StoryBoard appear well, but when go to the next StoryBoard, the view appear with normallity, but at two seconds appear the black screen in my view.

Comment: @AntonioUreba Can you try by removing the code for transition style

`homeVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
homeVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

With

```
homeVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
```

Comment: The first StoryBoard appear well, but when go to the next StoryBoard, the view appear with normallity, but at two seconds appear the black screen in my view.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set backgroundColor,
I was facing Blackscreen too, but i fixed it by change the backgroundColor

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

Comment: The first StoryBoard appear well, but when go to the next StoryBoard, the view appear with normallity, but at two seconds appear the black screen in my view.

Comment: Try to use ViewControllerClassGoHere.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen